# Which quests can be completed while in a raid group?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I noticed that the daily quest "Among the Champions", part of the Argent Tournament, in Icecrown can be completed while in a raid group.

Are there any other quests that share this property?

EDIT: I noticed on the quest page on Wowhead, [someone has pointed out that this quest may be bugged](http://bit.ly/MTTR4U) because it can be completed in a raid group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple quests that can be completed during raids and most of them will also require you to have a raid to complete them if attempted at the appropriated level.

What is common for them is that they will most likely be marked at [Raid](http://www.wowhead.com/quests=3) or [PvP](http://www.wowhead.com/quests=6) and they will usually be part of a chain that revolves around a Raid instance or battleground.